# discord.py on_member_update on one server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

`on_member_update` triggers for each guild the user is in. So whenever I change activity, if I'm in 10 servers where the bot is in, It will trigger `print(before.id)` 10 times.

How do I make `on_member_update` trigger once for each member?

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
     print(before.id)
```

---

Edit:

I tried adding `@commands.cooldown(1, 60, type=commands.BucketType.user)` but it doesn't seem to work with listeners.

---

I also tried, but the cooldown only works if I type the command in discord.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    user_id = before.id
    await self.play_time(user_id)

@commands.cooldown(1, 60, type=commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.command()
async def play_time(self, user_id):
    print(user_id)
```

---

This is what i'm trying to do:
Is there a way I can add a cooldown on `play_time` function for a user

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        user_id = before.id
        game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing" and str(i.name) == "League of Legends"]
        game_before = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing" and str(i.name) == "League of Legends"]   
        
        if game_after:
            self.start = time.time()  
             
        elif game_before:
            self.end = time.time()
            await self.play_time(user_id, self.start, self.end)
    
    
    async def play_time(self,user_id , start, end):
        result = end - start
        hours, rem = divmod(result, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
        
        try:
            conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=host,
                database=database,
                user=user,
                password=password,
                port=port)
            
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM playtime WHERE user_id = '{user_id}'""")
            data = cur.fetchone()
            if data is not None:
                playtime_data = list(data)
                user_time = playtime_data[1]
                updated_time = user_time + seconds
                cur.execute(f"""UPDATE playtime SET time = {updated_time}
                            WHERE user_id = '{user_id}'""")
                conn.commit()
                cur.close()
            else:
                cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO playtime(user_id, time)
                            VALUES ('{user_id}', {seconds})""")
                conn.commit()
                cur.close()
                
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
        else:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem a little more clearly?

Comment: So my bot is in 10 servers, and I'm in the 10 servers the bot is in. and whenever `on_member_update` is triggered it will run `print(before.id)` 10 times.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I also have a bot and I do not face such a problem. Did you test this code?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I found questions with the same problem but none have answers.

Comment: Hey, I tested ir again and no problems. When i change a nickname it's running 1 times and the bot was in 15 servers. Maybe you can check your all code.

Comment: A nickname changes in a single server @Weylyn, try changing your username or avatar.

Comment: @Ceres this event is `on_member_update` not `on_user_update`.  `on_member_update` checks for display names, activities, statuses, roles and is pending in guilds. So if i change my username, `on_member_update` will not trigger.

Comment: can you try after.activities and see how many time it runs?

Comment: @Weylyn, my bad but you get the idea. It can be triggered multiple times for a single event.

Comment: @Rashid i didn't got what you mean.

Comment: @Ceres if you and your bot in 2 mutual servers and you change username, the bot will trigger `on_member_update` event 2 times. `on_member_update` runs many times if user and bot has multiple mutual servers.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. I want to limit `on_member_update` to once per user even if me and the bot are in 2 mutual servers.

Comment: I don't think you can control when the event triggers, if you could tell how you are using it, there might be a fix

Comment: I added what im trying to do in the question

Comment: Have you tried using a short-term storage system?

Comment: what do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found out that you can achieve this by checking what the guild id is.

For Example:

```
if before.guild.id == 1234:
     #run code
else:
     #handle this however you would like
```

Comment: Also... you are able to do this for multiple guilds obviously. So if you wanted to do something else for a different guild, then just add another if then statement.